# change nginx rewrite regex condition

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

My rewrite rule is currently:

```
rewrite ^/answer/1/(www\.)*(.)(.+)$ /answer/1/$2.html last;
```

So requests such as:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/aa
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa/
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa/something
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa/something/even-deeper/and-so-on
```

Provides the document:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/a.html
```

Now I want to split the response so that requests such as:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/aa
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa/
```

will provide the previous document:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/a.html
```

But requests that go any further such as:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa/something
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa/something/even-deeper/and-so-on
```

will provide the new document:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/new.html
```

How should I change the above regex condition to accommodate the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at home so i could not test it right now but something like this should work:

```
rewrite ^/answer/1/(www\.)*(.)(.+)/(.+)$ /answer/1/new.html break;
rewrite ^/answer/1/(www\.)*(.)(.+)$ /answer/1/$2.html last;
```

Let me explain: as stated in the nginx docs ([here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html))

```
break
stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives;
```

so if a request match the first rewrite rule (that is similar to your rewrite but ends with the `/(.+)` directive. This means that will match every request that was already matching but if and only if it is followed by 1 or more character after the slash. Beware of this because this means that the following url:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/www.aa// (yes this is a valid url)
```

will redirect to:

```
mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/new.html
```

if you don't want this beahaviour you can modify the regex as follow:

```
rewrite ^/answer/1/(www\.)*(.)(.+)/(([^/]+/?)+)$ /answer/1/new.html break;
```

here the `(([^/]+/?)+)` directive say: everything that is NOT a / repeated one or more time and that may be or not be followed by a /. all of this repeated one or more time.

I repeat, i am not able to test it right now but it should work as you expect. Remember that here the order of the rewrite url as i am testing FIRST for the url that should rewrite to `mydomain.co.uk/answer/1/new.html` and then there is your old rewrite that will still match the url but will not be processed by nginx since the `break` keyword of the previous rule.

edit: i confused `last` and `break` :)

Comment: Works but needed to change break to last (so both of them will have last) Thanks!